# Cannot skip cypress test based on environment variable

Tags: jenkins, environment-variables, cypress, skip

I am trying to skip a few cypress tests within a certain jenkins environment.  My cypress tests look like this:

```js
if (!Cypress.env.DEV_JENKINS) {
    it.only("should run if not on a the DEV_JENKINS environment", () => {
       // ...
    });
    
    // more tests
  }
```

I know that this code works to skip tests, because if I change it to `if (Cypress.env.DEV_JENKINS)`, the tests are skipped, because there is no environment variable set.

I am trying every possible way described in the cypress docs to set this environment variable from the cli.  Here are a few things I've tried:

```
npx cypress run --env DEV_JENKINS=true

CYPRESS_DEV_JENKINS=true npx cypress run

export CYPRESS_DEV_JENKINS=true && npx cypress run
```

It seems like no matter what I do, the tests are not being skipped.  I have a feeling I'm not setting the env variable correctly, but I don't see whats wrong.  How can I successfully set the environment variable from my jenkins pipeline so that cypress will register it and skip certain tests based on the above code?

Answer (score 0):

Env variables are strings, so

```js
if (Cypress.env.DEV_JENKINS !== 'true') {
```

is a bit more explicit.

---

Are you trying to skip by not setting DEV_JENKINS?

```js
if (!Cypress.env.DEV_JENKINS) {
```

should skip if you don't have the env.

If you ran it first with DEV_JENKINS and then without, is the env variable persisting for the 2nd run?